# Angular2 initialize user before app starts

Tags: angular

My app has `api_token` in localstorage, and I want to determine a user using `api_token` from my REST before app starts. How can I do that? I've used routeResolvers, but I want to determine a user before app starts instead determine a user when route starts.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to run some code before bootstrapping Angular, then you can just... run some code outside of Angular and have that code bootstrap the app.

For example:

```js
// main.ts
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

// Here, some code retrieving api_token from localStorage.

// Only call the line below once your code is done.
// You might have to place that line in a callback of some sort.
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

But I suspect you want to run code AND pass the retrieved value to Angular. In that case, take a look at `APP_INITIALIZER`. See [explanation + code sample](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9047#issuecomment-224075188).

Comment: Thanks for the post.  An alternative to APP_INITIALIZER would be to use localStorage for passing data into Angular.