# Is it possible to execute vanilla javascript before angular boot?

Tags: angular

I want to execute a javascript snippet that check whatever the browser supports angular or not. In the second case the script will do a redirect towards a static html webpage.

My intent is not rely on polyfills to support outdated browsers, but give a nice UX anyway by inviting the visitor to access my website with a modern browser.

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't see why not - put it in your `index.html`

Comment: Angular might already be booting then though. Your main.ts file might be a better spot..

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41779787

Comment: @aviadP. wouldn't in that way be executed in each page of my angular app?

Comment: Angular is a SPA, so `index.html` is processed once, then all the view changes are performed in javascript

Answer (score 1):

In your main.ts

```
//replace this
//    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
//      .catch(err => console.error(err));

//by some like:

if (executeAjavaScriptFunction())
{
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
     .catch(error=>console.log(error))
}
else
{
  alert("improve your navigator");
}
```

Or you can also write in your .html some like

```
  <app-root>
   If you can't see the application visit www.myoldpage.com
  </app-root>
```

Comment: But...if I wrote it inside of main.ts wouldn't I be forced to compile as es5 for it to be processed in IE? Moreover, wouldn't the compiler give me error if I used something like window.agent?